# Neo4j cartesian product limit - query optimization

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Given following schema

[image]

I need to get a list of `Collection` each with set of `ProductCard` (it's `Product` variant) matching criteria specified by user:

- type of collection
- 1..4 types of product (For each selected `ProductType` there must be one `ProductCard` in set.)
- price for set

I started with query like this

```
MATCH (c:Collection {type: 'selected_collection_type'})<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(pt1:ProductType {title: '1st product type'}), (c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(pt2:ProductType {title: '2nd product type'}),(c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(pt3:ProductType {title: '3rd product type'}), (c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(pt4:ProductType {title: '4th product type'})
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
WITH {c} AS c, {pt1} AS pt1, {pt2} AS pt2, {pt3} AS pt3, {pt4} AS pt4
    MATCH (pt1)<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p1:Product)-[:FROM_COLLECTION]->(c), (pt2)<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p2:Product)-[:FROM_COLLECTION]->(c), (pt3)<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p3:Product)-[:FROM_COLLECTION]->(c), (pt4)<-[:OF_TYPE]-(p4:Product)-[:FROM_COLLECTION]->(c), (pc1:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p1), (pc2:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p2), (pc3:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p3), (pc4:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p4)
    WHERE (pc1.price + pc2.price + pc3.price + pc4.price < price_margin_for_set)
    RETURN pc1, pc2, pc3, pc4, (p1.weight + p2.weight + p3.weight + p4.weight) AS sweight ORDER BY sweight DESC LIMIT 1
', {c:c, pt1:pt1, pt2:pt2, pt3:pt3, pt4:pt4}) YIELD value
RETURN c, value ORDER BY value.sweight DESC LIMIT 8;
```

and it works quite well for up to 3 selected product types but when I add 4th product type things just slow down drastically. Problem here is that I just need 1 set returned from subquery but cartesian product computed from all product variants (`Product` can have 1..~10 `ProductCard`) is rather big for 4 types.

How to optimize this query for performance/reduce variations count needed to return 1 set matching price criteria from subquery?

Here is EXPLAIN
[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkElb.png)

EDIT:
slightly changed the query

```
WITH ['Product Type 1', 'Product Type 2', 'Product Type 3', 'Product Type 4'] as types
MATCH (c:Collection)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(pt:ProductType)
WHERE pt.title in types AND c.type = 'collection type'
WITH c, size(types) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT pt) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
WITH {c} AS c 
MATCH (c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(p1:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:ProductType {title: "Product Type 1"})
MATCH (pc1:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p1)
MATCH (c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(p2:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:ProductType {title: "Product Type 2"})
MATCH (pc2:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p2)
MATCH (c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(p3:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:ProductType {title: "Product Type 3"})
MATCH (pc3:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p3)
MATCH (c)<-[:FROM_COLLECTION]-(p4:Product)-[:OF_TYPE]->(:ProductType {title: "Product Type 4"})
MATCH (pc4:ProductCard)-[:VARIANT_OF]->(p4)
WHERE (pc1.price + pc2.price + pc3.price + pc4.price < 1000)
RETURN pc1, pc2, pc3, pc4, (p1.weight + p2.weight + p3.weight + p4.weight) AS sweight ORDER BY sweight DESC LIMIT 1
', {c:c}) YIELD value
RETURN DISTINCT c, value LIMIT 8;
```

Explain

[image: whole query]

Explain of subquery

[image: subquery]

Comment: Why do you nedd the `apoc.cypher.run` procedure, I don't see the point here ... Moreover can you give the explain of the query, and also the one inside the  `apoc.cypher.run` ?

Comment: I've slightly changed query - with first one I started to get error: Found no solution for block size ...
Explains added and the apoc.cypher.run was my attempt to limit returned sets to 1 because I need only 1 set per Collection

Comment: I don't understand that either the query would be much easier if you just took the first part and added your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to break the Cartesian Product is to add logic so that one set clearly trumps the rest. Example

```
WHERE p1.value > p2.value > p3.value > p4.value
```

However, the nature of this query still results in lots of sets with minor insignificant changes. I would instead just return `WHERE p1.value < 1000 WITH COLLECT(p1) as possible`, and handle the rest client side to minimize data transfer. (If you really want, you could order p1 by value when collecting, and then sum the smallest 3, and than filter out any with a value more than `1000-smallest_set` but that feels a bit overkill)